# Как сократить количество условных директив?

Tags: c, linux

Есть макрос вида

```
#define WRITE_TO_FILE = "command"
```

Если он вообще определен, то надо открыть файл на чтение и запись и записать туда значение макроса, а если не определен, то окрыть файл просто на чтение. То есть

```
#ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
    FILE *file = fopen("файл", "r+b");
#else
    FILE *file = fopen("файл", "rb");
#endif
```

и немного далее

```
#ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
    fwrite(WRITE_TO_FILE, 1, sizeof(WRITE_TO_FILE) - 1, file);
#endif
```

Проблема в том, что таких директив в коде довольно много и он плохо читаем. Есть ли способ как-то это все подсократить?

Answer (score 5):

А чем не нравится читаемость кода? Мне лично нравятся условные директивы - все ясно и понятно.

Но уж если они так достали, предлагаю такой вариант. Все условно комилируемые вызовы функций запихнуть в макросы. Например, так (в случае вашего примера)

```
#ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
  #define myopenf(x) (fopen((x), "r+b"))
  #define myfwrite(x) (fwrite((WRITE_TO_FILE), 1, (sizeof(WRITE_TO_FILE) - 1), (x)) )
#else
  #define myopenf(x) (fopen((x), "rb"))
  #define (myfwrite(x))
#endif
```

И потом вызывать

```
FILE* file = myopenf("file_name");
myfwrite (file);
```

Так оно побыстрее будет работать

Comment: Я б предпочел вместо того, чтобы лепить макросы - сделать просто набор своих ф-ций. Увы, это С, а не С++, так что тут с теми же namespace не поиграешься =(

Comment: Ну да, и при неопределенном WRITE_TO_FILE вызывать функции, которые ничего не делают. Где же понятия об оптимизации?

Comment: а об этом не беспокойтесь. Современные компиляторы могут эффективно отбрасывать пустые функции и в результате в исполнимом файле нет и следа.

Comment: Неизвестно на каком компиляторе это будет компилироваться. Это и может gcc, который находится практически на cutting edge развития современных C/C++ компилятор, так и какой-нить древний cc из поставки древнючей версии юникса.

А касательно WRITE_TO_FILE - это еще надо было догадаться так обозвать макрос, который хранит константный строковый литерал с именем файла!!! Абсолютно неочевидно. По виду это скорее похоже было на флаг. BTW, абсолютно не вижу причин в конкретно данном ПО использовать условную компиляцию, а не брать эту настройку, скажем, из ini-файла.

Comment: Ну, нужно ему сделать это через условную компиляцию. Ну, хочется так. Пусть сделает.

Answer (score 3):

Если отличия только такие, как Вы описали, то сделайте две функции (скажем myfopen() и myfwrite() ) в которых будут #ifdef и вызывайте их вместо блока кода с #ifdef.